# Modify Java source code programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse-emf, eclipse-jdt

I used the EMF ANT-Task XSD2Java to generate Java code from an existing XSD. Unfortunately the ANT-Task works not as correct as the manual tool and generates a package like 'org.example.interface.something'. Thus the key-word 'interface' is not allowd as a package name I want to refactor it to make the code run. (btw doing it via the UI the package name is 'org.example.interface_.something')
My question is: How to refactor the package name including dependencies in the source files? Can I use JDT and if, how?
Thanks for any hints.
Kai

Comment: Search and replace? If there's a similar pattern, that would probably be the easiest.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the package name in the package explorer. Then from the menu click Refactor -> Rename.

[image]

Comment: Actually I need to do it from source code, not manually, because it should be executed by a nightly build. An ANT-Task for this job would be nice, too, but is not neccessary.

Answer (score 0):

As tjameson suggested,

```
find -name *.java | 
xargs sed -i s/org.example.interface.something/org.example.interface_.something/g
```

will work?